# django-permission allow all @decorator

Tags: django, django-permissions

An app I have been hired to work on is using [django-permission](https://github.com/lambdalisue/django-permission).

Every view in the application requires authentication, but I need to create a simple way so I can have endpoints that doesn't require authentication. One usecase is for /callbacks.

I would like to create a custom decorator that I can use for such views.

Any hints or examples?

What I would prefer is:

```
@permission_required('none')
def callback_transloadit(request, pres_id):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt


def allow_all(self):
    return True

@user_passes_test(allow_all)
@csrf_exempt
def callback_transloadit(request, pres_id):
```